# How can I create a custom Android Device Profile for AVD manager?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, avd-manager, virtual-device-manager

Let's say I have a device other than Google's Pixel devices, so how can I create a custom hardware profile for my device.

For example, if I have a Nokia Android phone how can I create a custom hardware profile for that one.

I'm currently a beginner in android development, so if anybody can help me.

Thanks and gratitude in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using Android Studio (4.1):

1. Tools > AVD Manager
2. Create Virtual Device
3. New Hardware Profile
4. Fill out all the options
5. Finish
6. Optional: Find the device definition on the list, right-click, and Export to an XML

Using the command line (i.e., `avdmanager`):

- [How to create AVD from command line using a hardware profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64503182/1766230)